# (Kotlin) Communcation between Fragments in MVVM

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm

I'm trying to understand the concepts of MVVM but i'm having a hard time trying to understand how to communicate between The model class and UI (The fragment) in this case.

Here's the (shitty, be aware) code:

**LoginFragment.kt**

```
class LoginFragment: Fragment(), AuthListener {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<CredentialsLoginFragmentBinding>(
        inflater,
        R.layout.credentials_login_fragment,
        container,
        false
    )
    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
    val view: View = binding.root
    val registerButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.register_button)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    viewModel.authListener = this

    registerButton.setOnClickListener {
        val transaction: FragmentTransaction? = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        transaction?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, SignupFragment())?.commit()
    }
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val constraintRoot: MotionLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_root)
    ActivityUtils().switchLayoutAnimationKeyboard(constraintRoot = constraintRoot)

}

override fun onStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onSuccess() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onError(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}}
```

**LoginViewModel.kt**

```
class LoginViewModel: ViewModel(){
var username: String? = null
var password: String? = null
var isCredentialsValid: Boolean = false
var authListener: AuthListener? = null
private val context: Context? = null

fun onLoginButtonClicked(view: View){

    if(username.isNullOrEmpty() || password.isNullOrEmpty()){
        authListener?.onError("Invalid username or password")
        isCredentialsValid = false
        return
    }

    if(!username.isNullOrEmpty() && password!!.length >= 8){
        isCredentialsValid = true
        authListener?.onSuccess()
    }else{
        authListener?.onError("Invalid")
    }
}}
```

Lets assume now that I enter an username and password and both meet the criteria. Now i'd like to, when i click on the "Log in" button, the current fragment is replaced by a menu fragment, for example.

How could i achieve something like that ? I've tried to replace from the ViewModel class, but that doesn't work. 
Should I take the result of "isCredentialsValid" from the VM class and respond accordingly in the LoginFragment class ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use live data for updating the data from viewModel to view. I will post the code how it should be, but make sure that you need to understand the concept of LiveData.

LoginViewModel.kt

```
class LoginViewModel: ViewModel(){
var username: String? = null
var password: String? = null
var isCredentialsValid: Boolean = false
var authListener: AuthListener? = null
private val context: Context? = null
// LiveData to udpate the UI
private val _isValidCredential = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isValidCredential: LiveData<Boolean> = _isValidCredential


fun onLoginButtonClicked(view: View){

if(username.isNullOrEmpty() || password.isNullOrEmpty()){
    authListener?.onError("Invalid username or password")
    isCredentialsValid = false
    return
}

if(!username.isNullOrEmpty() && password!!.length >= 8){
    isCredentialsValid = true
// to update the value of live data wherever you need
    _isValidCredential.value = true
    authListener?.onSuccess()
}else{
    authListener?.onError("Invalid")
// to update the value of live data wherever you need
    _isValidCredential.value = false
}
}
}
```

Your Fragment should be

LoginFragment.kt

```
class LoginFragment: Fragment(), AuthListener {

override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater,
container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<CredentialsLoginFragmentBinding>(
    inflater,
    R.layout.credentials_login_fragment,
    container,
    false
)
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
val view: View = binding.root
val registerButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.register_button)
binding.viewModel = viewModel
viewModel.authListener = this

// This is the way you need to observe the value
viewModel.isValidCredential.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

if(it){
// do your navigation stuff here
}else{
// do your stuff if not valid credential
}

    })

registerButton.setOnClickListener {
    val transaction: FragmentTransaction? = 
fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
    transaction?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, SignupFragment())?.commit()
}
return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
val constraintRoot: MotionLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_root)
ActivityUtils().switchLayoutAnimationKeyboard(constraintRoot = constraintRoot)

}

override fun onStarted() {
Toast.makeText(context, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onSuccess() {
Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onError(message: String) {
Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}}
```

Comment: @BenAndJerrys upvoting the answer may be useful for others to refer

Comment: I'm too new for that i believe

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of communicating back to the UI from the view model is using [livedata](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).  In your LoginViewModel, you would set your livedata to either `true` or `false`.  Inside your view `LoginFragment.kt` you would have an observer.  This observers job is to fire anytime a livedata's value has changed. That way you can have logic in your view that can either shows an error message liveData = false or launch the menu fragment = true.

Here is a good example using livedata to pass data to the view (fragment) this in the docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement